# SFML Vector2 usage

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

In SFML, I understand `Vector2`s as pair or points. There are:

```
sf::Vector2f float

sf::Vector2i int(signed)

sf::Vector2u unsigned int
```

Am I correct?
What about `long int`s and `long long int`s and `double`s and `long double`s?
I think there is only these three kinds of `Vector2`s.
I don't need to use it anywhere, but I'm just wondering.
Thanks.

Comment: If SFML doesn't provide names for those, you can make them yourself with `typedef Vector2<long in> Vector2l`.

Comment: [`sf::Vector2` is templated](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1Vector2.php). As the docs say, "`sf::Vector2<float>` is `sf::Vector2f`." If you want a `double` one, just use `sf::Vector2<double>`. The reason these other ones (i.e. `sf::Vector2d`) aren't provided by default is because they're less common.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc :

> You generally don't have to care about the templated form
>   (`sf::Vector2<T>`), the most common specializations have special
>   typedefs:
>
> `sf::Vector2<float>` is `sf::Vector2f`
>
> `sf::Vector2<int>` is `sf::Vector2i`
>
> `sf::Vector2<unsigned int>` is `sf::Vector2u`

You can use `sf::Vector<T>` instead of `sf::Vector2f`/`sf::Vector2i`/`sf::Vector2u` if you want to specialize it.